# Are there any registration/authentication api's which can be used in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm developing an IoS and Android app using react-native, and am now starting to consider all the aspects of user registration, so that typically the person will provide some credentials, and then get sent an email (or possibly sms) enabling them to "verify" their account, after which point they are a registered user.

These registration processes (and subsequent emails/sms's seem to be fairly common , so I'm wondering if there are any API's which anyone has come across which make the job of creating the registration/activation process easier m rather than writing code from scratch ?

Many thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want when you ask for an `API`. If you're developing backend as well you can use [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/react-native/00-login).

If you want just to implement frontend, I guess you have to write your own code. Consider using something like redux or mobx to store your email and other things after logging in.

Anyways the REST part you have to write on your own. As for views you can google for it, for example there's [react-native-login-screen](https://github.com/dwicao/react-native-login-screen)